# distance matrix api - how to set destination by user?

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-maps

I used this code(this is code for calculating the distance between two cities):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>

<input id="orig" type="text" style="width:35em"><br><br>
Vaša lokacija: <input id="dest" type="text" style="width:35em"><br><br>
Udaljenost: <input id="dist" type="text" style="width:35em">
<button onclick="" >Izračunaj!</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var origin = "Zagreb",
destination = "Cakovec",
service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

service.getDistanceMatrix(
{
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
}, 
callback
);

function callback(response, status) {
var orig = document.getElementById("orig"),
    dest = document.getElementById("dest"),
    dist = document.getElementById("dist");

if(status=="OK") {
    orig.value = response.destinationAddresses[0];
    dest.value = response.originAddresses[0];
    dist.value = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
} else {
    alert("Error: " + status);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And trying to get result as user input the city but nothing...I tried with document.getelementbyid but then script not working. Only working as pre-writen in html. So if i wrote in HTML origin ="A" and destination= "B" it will calculate distance from A to B but in browser, data can't be changed...

What i want to make is: 1.To set first destination value as fixed 2. user type in his location 3. button with function to calculate on click distance from fixed location (set before) to his location.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best would be if you create a fiddle, that demonstrates your issue!!!

Comment: well I guess that doesn't everyone knows everything, also if I'm not trying to figure it out, then what...I could never learn new stuff, and I came here for help, at least this site is for helping I guess....

Comment: You don´t have to know everything, but If you want to drink water from a bottle you need at least to know how to open a bottle, right? The things you don´t know, are the basic of the basic! However, just update your code or create a fiddle and I will help you through this anyway, ok?

Comment: Add your code here please, that helps us to help you: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens, because you don´t try to get the **value** of the element. You just select the element.

So your have to change your code like:

```
var orig = document.getElementById("orig").value,
dest = document.getElementById("dest").value,
dist = document.getElementById("dist").value;
```

It always helps to `console.log(orig)`, so you can see what you have!

```js
var x = document.getElementById('orig');
console.log("this is just the element");
console.log(x);
console.log("----------------------------------");
var x = document.getElementById('orig').value;
console.log("this is the VALUE of the selected element");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<input id="orig" type="text" style="width:35em" value="MyPlaceToCalculate">
```

Comment: Im not sure do i just copy this or need to change something in this im not familiar to console.log

Comment: `console.log` is **the fundamental of web development** if you want to program for web, get familiar! However, you have to update your code to, what you currently have (included my suggestions) otherwise **we can´t help you**

Comment: And how `console.log` works, is perfectly demonstrated in my provided code snippet